# License for stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar and stanford-english-corenlp-models-current.jar?

Tags: stanford-nlp

What is the license for the Standford CoreNLP model libraries stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar and stanford-english-corenlp-models-current.jar? Are they licensed under GPL v2, like the rest of Standford CoreNLP? I unzipped the .jar files, but couldn't find any license information.

If they are licensed GPL v2, where is the source code for generating the serialized data in these libraries?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software licensing and not programming as defined in the [help]. Software licensing questions are off-topic here.

Comment: This is not the right place to be asking about legal questions. But, I believe the models are licensed the same as the main codebase. The source data used to create them, however, is certainly not. You'll need to get in touch with the LDC to get a license for that data.